# Java Stream.collect groupingBy and aggregated classes

Tags: java, lambda, group-by

This code is straightforward :

```
Map<String, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(BlogPost::getType));
```

where BlogPost is :

```
class BlogPost {
    String title;
    String author;
    String type;
    int likes;
    // getter setter
}
```

What if BlogPost has some other classes as fields and I want to group by one of those fields, e.g.

```
class BlogPost {
    String title;
    String author;
    Description description;
    int likes;
    // getter setter
}

class Description {
    String part1;
    String type;
    // getter setter
}
```

How can I access say

```
myBlogPost.getDescription().getType()
```

inside a lambda expression?

Pseudo code:

```
Map<String, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(BlogPost::getDescription::getType));
```

edit :
groupingBy refers to :

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

Comment: It is a duplicate question indeed. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(bp -> bp.getDescription().getType()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a lambda returning that expression:

```
groupingBy(p -> p.getDescription().getType())
```